# Consulta Jerarquica ascendente MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, jerarquía

Hola estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde parte de este es mostrar los jefes hasta el director donde la tabla es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por ejemplo si entro con un jefe clase b (id = 7) deberia mostrar

```
Sub-Director B

Director General
```

estoy trabajando con mysql la tabla se llama puestos.

Perdon por no agregar codigo pero no se como comenzar.

Comment: ¿Te ha servido la respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar una consulta, con estas condiciones:

1. Que el jefe sea NULL, ya que el Director General siempre va ser el jefe del usuario.
2. Que el id del jefe siempre sea menor que el del usuario.
3. Que el jefe tenga la misma letra que el usuario (A,B), para esto puedes utilizar un [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).

Con esto la consulta quedaría, para el usuario con id = 7:

```
SELECT
  p1.id,
  p1.nombre
FROM
  puestos p1
WHERE
  p1.jefe IS NULL OR 
  p1.jefe <
     (SELECT p2.jefe FROM puestos p2 WHERE p2.id = 7 AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(p1.nombre, ' ', -1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(p2.nombre, ' ', -1))
```

Dejo el ejemplo en http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1f57f/3

Comment: Fíjate en que, para el `id=8`, tu consulta no funcionaría :( Los jefes los marca el campo `jefe` no su clase

Answer (score 0):

Va a ser necesaria una búsqueda iterativa, tal que así:

```
set @i=7;
SELECT nombre FROM puestos JOIN (
    SELECT IF(id=@i,id,NULL) subordinados,
      IF(id=@i,@i:=jefe,NULL) jefes
      FROM puestos
      ORDER BY jefe DESC,id DESC  
  ) c1 ON id=jefes;
```

Para la que adjunto el dataset de pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS puestos (
  id int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  nombre varchar(48) NOT NULL,
  jefe int(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO puestos (id, nombre, jefe) VALUES
    (1, 'Director general', null),
    (2, 'Sub-director A', 1),
    (3, 'Sub-director B', 1),
    (4, 'Jefe Clase B', 3),
    (5, 'Jefe Clase A', 2),
    (6, 'Jefe Clase A', 2),
    (7, 'Jefe Clase B', 3),
    (8, 'Vendedor Clase A', 4),
    (9, 'Vendedor Clase A', 4);
```